# Run a Node endpoint for every item in array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, node.js, express

I am using ExpressJs, NodeJs, AngularJs.

Let's say I have an array with several objects that represent grocery store accounts and the amount owed to them by the bank.

```
[{
account: 1, 
amount: 2.33
}, 
{
account: 2, 
amount: 5.99
}, 
{
account: 3, 
amount: 6.00
}];
```

This array can change and can have 1 object or 10 objects in the array, just depends on what grocery stores the bank owes to that week.

For each object, I need to run a Node endpoint that will transfer that money. 
For example:

```
const app = module.exports = express();
app.post('/transfer', (req, res) => { //Code goes in here };
```

How do I run app.post('/transfer') *n* amount of times, depending on the amount of objects in the array?

Still a noob so I'm having a hard time wording my question.
To make it simple: Run a function for every item in array.

2 items = run function twice. (async)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass that array in the **request body** and call an auxiliary function that performs the transfer for each item in the array:

```
app.post('/transfer', (req, res) => {
  const accounts = req.body;

  accounts.forEach((account) => transfer(account));
};

function transfer(account) {
  // perform the transfer for a single account
}
```

That auxiliary function can be async, returning a promise, and you can use `Promise.all` to resolve all the transfers:

```
app.post('/transfer', (req, res) => {

  const accounts = req.body;
  const transferPromises = accounts.map((account) => transfer(account));

  Promise.all(transferPromises).then(...).catch(...);
};

function transfer(account) {
  // returns a promise of transfer for a single account
}
```

Comment: Oh man thanks so much! I forget how useful higher-order functions can be. I honestly didn't think it was possible but it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! :)